# Custom post type structure + permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I need to create this structure:

- example.com/animals (with all animals classes)
- example.com/animals/classes (with all animals of this classes)
- example.com/animals/classes/animal_name (the animal's page)

I doubt that the following solution is correct:

I created a **Custom post type** "animals" with this rule `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'animals/%classes%')` where **classes** is my custom taxonomy.

And I added this filter to make the rewrite work.

```
function addTaxonomyInUrl($post_link, $id = 0) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if(is_object($post) ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'classes');
        if($terms) { 
            return str_replace('%classes%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter ('post_type_link','addTaxonomyInUrl',1,3);
```

This works well except for two things:

1 - the page example.com/animals, I tried to create it as an archive temaplate of animals but dosen't work. (for the moment I workarounded the problem using a normale page)

2 - the rewite of animal's pages, example.com/animals/reptiles/python works well but if I change "reptiles" with something else ex. example.com/animals/**foo**/python I keep on seeing the Python page instead of a 404 error.

Could you plesse give me some suggestions?

Comment: The archive is controlled by the `has_archive` argument when you register your post type. The second issue is normal behavior, posts are queried by post name alone. The canonical link should take care of any SEO problems this may introduce, but if you want to 404 those pages, you'll have to check terms and do it manually.

Comment: Thank you Milo, I have forgotten to write that I'm already using the has_archive argument, but it doesn't work, Do you think that it's possibile that the problem is the rewrite argument? In your opinion is this the best pratices I can do?